# What does LS mean and how do I rinse it away

Tags: json, laravel-5, response

[image: When I run artisan serve command][image: Here is a screen-shot]I am trying to render a json-response but it is strange with "ls" before. I am building an app with a Laravel backend and a react-frontend. How shall I iterate through this? I have tried both with fetch and axios. I get the attached response from Postman.

Now I found the problem but how do I make "php artisan serve" not run "ls" before starting the development server? That "ls" bloats all my returns so I cannot parse them and iterate through them.

Comment: Have you tried searching through the project files for some stupid echo 'ls' print 'ls' etc left accidently...?

Comment: I think you are right! I tried to run another unserved endpoint and before the error-HTML, the 'ls' showed up again. But where can it be generated?

Comment: Unfortunately it can be anywhere, inside a route closure, any controller, anywhere. That's why I recommend running some grep/find/search over whole project.